# Params Return Undefined after componentWillReceiveProps called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a React component, that when a button is clicked, takes the user to a new URL for a different day using the `<Link />` component and it should render the events/games for that day (same component but should fetch new data). The URL updates, but the `this.params.day` - for instance - returns undefined, however when using React Dev tools, it's there and I can see it, and it has updated for the next day... I am relying on React Router's params to grab the correct data, I'm a little stuck on why I can't get it to re-render the components correctly. Here are the important parts of the component:

```
class Games extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      games: [],
      month: '',
      day: '',
      year: '',
      nextDay: '',
      prevDay: ''
    };

    // this.prevDay = this.prevDay.bind(this);
    // this.nextDay = this.nextDay.bind(this);
  }


  // set the state of the app based on the date
  parseDate(){
    // if we have params in the url
    if( this.props.params.month && this.props.params.day && this.props.params.year ){
      this.setState({
        month: moment(this.props.params.month, 'MM').format('MM'),
        day: moment(this.props.params.day, 'DD').format('DD'),
        year: moment(this.props.params.year, 'YYYY').format('YYYY'),
      });
    } else{
      // no params? set the date to today
      this.setState({
        month: moment().format('MM'),
        day: moment().format('DD'),
        year: moment().format('YYYY'),
      });
    }
    console.log('Date parsed.');
  }

  testProps(props){
    console.log('FIRED & Params: ' + this.props.params.day);
  }

  // generate previous day
  prevDay(){
    let currentDate = this.state.month+this.state.day+this.state.year,
        prevDate = moment(currentDate, 'MMDDYYYY').subtract(1, 'days').format('MM/DD/YYYY');
    this.setState({
      prevDay: prevDate
    });
  }

  // Generate next day
  nextDay(){
    let currentDate = this.state.month+this.state.day+this.state.year,
        nextDate = moment(currentDate, 'MMDDYYYY').add(1, 'days').format('MM/DD/YYYY');
    this.setState({
      nextDay: nextDate
    });
  }

  // Grab games for current day
  getGames(){

    this.setState({loading: true});

    // error handling
    function handleErrors(response) {
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw Error(response.statusText + 'POOP!');
      }
      return response;
    }

    fetch(`http://mlb.mlb.com/gdcross/components/game/mlb/year_${this.state.year}/month_${this.state.month}/day_${this.state.day}/master_scoreboard.json`)
    //fetch(`http://localhost:3000/inprogress.json`)
    .then(handleErrors)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(games => {
      const gamesLoaded = games.data;

      this.setState({
        games: gamesLoaded,
        loading: false
      });
    })
    .catch(error => this.setState({games: 'Error Finding Games'}) );
    console.log('Games fetched.');
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    this.parseDate();
    console.log('Component Will Mount Fired');
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.getGames();
    this.prevDay();
    this.nextDay();
    console.log('Component Mounted');
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(){
    this.parseDate();
    // this.testProps();
    console.log(this.props.params.day);

    console.log('Component received props!');
  }
```

The most important part of this is the `parseDate()` function , as it should set the state of the component based on dates, but when called in `componentWillReceiveProps` the params are undefined, but yet they are visible in React Dev Tools.

Any thoughts and help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`componentWillRecieveProps`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) takes an argument of the new props. You want something like

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
  this.parseDate(newProps)
}
```

And have `parseDate` use the argument instead of `this.props`.

Comment: Ah got it, I can see how that works and i'm seeing the values. So, inside of my existing `parseDate` function, do I just add an a conditional statement to handle if `newProps` exists? Or would it be better to write a new function for updating? Do you have any good examples I could see or write ups? Thanks for the push in the right direction.

Comment: There are several ways you could do it, my approach would be to pass the props to `parseDate` and not use `this.props` there. So your cWRP would be like my answer, and in componentWillMount it would be `parseDate(this.props)`. I'm on my phone so I can't write a lot of code